# Updating a Variable for an Unwind Segue (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to update the UILabel on a previous Table View using an Unwinding Segue. I have everything working except I am bringing back blank text each time I select something on my modal. I am essentially bringing back the "" of the variable I am creating (myName).

However, I thought since I am updating the variable in my didSelectRowAtIndex that I would be bring that back. I did check to see if I am getting a value when selecting on the Modal and I am. So I think this is something as simple as updating the variable myName.

NewTableViewController (Modal):

```
var myName = ""

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let row = Int(indexPath.row)
    var selectedObject = objects[row] as! PFObject
    var selectedName = selectedObject["myName"] as! String

    myName = selectedName as String
    println(myName)
}
```

TableViewController (Source View Controller):

```
  @IBAction func unwindName(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    println("unwind working")
    if let svc = segue.sourceViewController as? NewTableViewController {
        self.myNameLabel.text = svc.myName
        println(myNameLabel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What variable in the controller you're going back to are you trying to update? How are you invoking your unwind segue? You have dismissViewControllerAnimated in your code; that is not an unwind segue, so are you actually doing an unwind?

Comment: I added the unwind segue. I know that part is working because I am updating the label (myNameLabel). However, it is updating with the first instance of myName variable, which is blank. I am trying to get the new selected name text.

Comment: If you have an unwind segue, why are you also dismissing? You shouldn't be doing both. How is the unwind triggered? Is it connected from a cell in NewTableViewController?

Comment: I thought I needed both (I am going to remove the dismiss, as you are correct no need for it.). Yes, the unwind is trigged by the selected cell in the NewTableViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke a segue (unwind or any other kind) from a cell, the segue will be executed before didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called, so you shouldn't set your variable value there (in fact you don't need to implement that method at all). You should implement prepareForSegue in the source view controller, and set the value of your variable there.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        var selectedObject = objects[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
        var selectedName = selectedObject["myName"] as! String

        myName = selectedName as String
    }
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense then it was not being executed. This will help me in a couple other areas as well. Thank you very much.